# Read from / write to files in J - `1!:2' doesn't work)

Tags: file, file-io, j

I'm trying [example from Learning J](http://www.rogerstokes.free-online.co.uk/28.htm) but it doesn't work. How do I write to/read from a file in J?

```
   F =: 'c:\temp\demofile.xyz'       NB. a filename
   'some data' 1!:2 < F    NB. write to file F
|file name error
|   'some data'    1!:2<F
```

I'm trying it under Windows 7.

Comment: This should work. Maybe you don't have permission to write to temp or it does not exist?

Comment: [Errors page:](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/jforc/error_messages.htm) "You specified a file name that is invalid, or attempted to read a nonexistent file."

Comment: @Eelvex You were right about permission (you can post it as an answer). I was confused by the error name and description. It seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Error messages in J are tricky like that. Many can't be interpreted literally.

Comment: @ArtemIce: well, it is you that found a solution, so *you* should post an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Eelvex suggested the problem was with writing permission to the folder 'c:\temp'. Yet the file name was fine, J produced `file name error` due to the lack of permissions.